# How to get specific objects from json arrays using nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have this sought of array

```
{
  "arr": [
    {
      "obj": [
        {
          "reg_at": 1519615460064,
          "id": "367790083"
        },
        {
          "reg_at": 1519615460064,
          "id": "41370460"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "obj": [
        {
          "reg_at": 1519615460065,
          "id": "215109021"
        },
        {
          "reg_at": 1519615460065,
          "id": "72173002"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and i want to all the id objects into one array like this:

```
[367790083, 41370460, 41370460]
```

please how do i go about achieving this using nodejs? i have tried looping through but am not getting the desired output.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can use a map function and for each object return what you need
https://codeburst.io/learn-understand-javascripts-map-function-ffc059264783

Comment: Like i said, i have tried looping through the array and pushing the IDs to an empty array but not getting the required result.

Comment: I admit the OP is a beginner but I don't see any problem with the question, so I guess down votes are for personal grudge against the OP.

Comment: You should try to research this one some more. This is honestly quite basic and you can easily find the solution with a little more digging (in case you're wondering why you're getting downvotes). Or at least write down what you've tried and we can tell you what the problem with your approach was.

Comment: You can use lodash or underscore to achieve this.

Comment: *i have tried looping through but am not getting the desired output.* Please share your attempt.

Answer (score 3):

Use `reduce` and `map`

```
var output = obj.arr.reduce( (a, c) => 
    a.concat( c.obj.map(  
       s => +s.id )  )  , [])
```

**Explanation**

- Use `reduce` to **iterate and accumulate** the output to `a`
- Use `map` to return the id (*number converted*) of every item in `obj` array inside `arr`

**Demo**

```js
var obj = {
  "arr": [
    {
      "obj": [
        {
          "reg_at": 1519615460064,
          "id": "367790083"
        },
        {
          "reg_at": 1519615460064,
          "id": "41370460"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "obj": [
        {
          "reg_at": 1519615460065,
          "id": "215109021"
        },
        {
          "reg_at": 1519615460065,
          "id": "72173002"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
var output = obj.arr.reduce( (a, c) => 
    a.concat( c.obj.map(  
       s => +s.id )  )  , []);
console.log( output );
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that you are a beginner I'll do this the good old fashioned way for you to understand how the data is organized.

```
var data = {
  "arr": [
    {
      "obj": [
        {
          "reg_at": 1519615460064,
          "id": "367790083"
        },
        {
          "reg_at": 1519615460064,
          "id": "41370460"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "obj": [
        {
          "reg_at": 1519615460065,
          "id": "215109021"
        },
        {
          "reg_at": 1519615460065,
          "id": "72173002"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

// The variable for the result
var result = [];

// "data" is the object and "arr" is an array and has a length
for (var i=0; i<data.arr.length; i++) {
    // For clarity, pick the current object from the array
    var theArrItem = data.arr[i];

    // That object then has a "obj" which is an array
    for (var j=0; j<theArrItem.obj.length; j++) {
        // Again, pick the current object
        var theObjItem = theArrItem.obj[j];
        // Add the id of the current object to the result
        result.push(theObjItem.id);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use lodash library as it has many inbuilt functions that can reduce coding on server side.

```
npm i --save lodash
_.map(arr, 'id');
```

Result will be [367790083, 41370460, 41370460]